# wampserver startup php error (right after installation/after setup)

Tags: php, filesystems, installation, wampserver

Right after setting up wampserver 2.5 (I am working on Win7, 64 bit) there have been many errors logged in the PHP error log (Wampserver trayicon -> PHP -> error log).

Errors in the log stated some missing .dll-Files although they existed in the right place (see PHP error.log).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case this solved the problem:

Copy the allegedly missing files (see PHP error log) to the folder

```
[root]/wamp/bin/apache/bin/
```

There the .dlls will be recognized.

Seems to be a common problem with the wampserver 2.5 distribution.

Answer (score 0):

It would have been useful to know which files it was reporting as missing but I assume it is these.

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 
  'd:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/ext/php_ldap.dll' 
  - The specified module could not be found.
```

And

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 
  'd:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/ext/php_intl.dll' 
  - The specified module could not be found
```

They are not that serious and the solution is very simple.

Using the wampmanager menu do the following, click on the apache version number, this will cause WAMPManager to rebuild the SYMLINK's in the apache folder to all the required files that live in the PHP folder.

```
(left click on) wampmanager then -> Apache -> Version -> Apache2.4.9
```

Answer (score -1):

Search the particular name.dll and download and place in the dll folder the issue will be solved and more easily you can use lot of dll fixer software which will fix all dll errors for you

Comment: Saying to use a "fixer" without being specific on which one, can cause some people to be put into a worse position than the one you're attempting to fix.